# How can I properly time animations in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, viewport

I planned on building a website and I don't seem to find any way to time the animations. Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .image {
        animation-name: appear;
        animation-duration: 5s;
      }
      
      .extremebig {
        font-size: 200px;
      }
      
      @keyframes appear {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1.0;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="extremebig">hello!</p>
    <img src="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/6/Red-Leafy-Apple-Fruit-Transparent-PNG.png" class="image"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

My idea of timing it is that the apple only starts appearing when it is visible to the visitor of the website.
Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Without js this is currently not possible. In future you might be able to use `@scroll-timeline` for such a task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS `animation-delay`. The code below should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .image {
        animation-name: appear;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-delay: /* However long you want the delay to be */;
      }
      
      .extremebig {
        font-size: 200px;
      }
      
      @keyframes appear {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1.0;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="extremebig">hello!</p>
    <img src="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/6/Red-Leafy-Apple-Fruit-Transparent-PNG.png" class="image"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does work but I think that they're asking about how to delay an animation until someone scrolls down to the apple on the website

Comment: yeah good point

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work:

```
function reveal() {
  var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".image");

  for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elementVisible = 150;

    if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
      reveals[i].classList.add("active");
    } else {
      reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
```

If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll try help you some more. :)

[Source](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/css-animations-scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

for that specific case you need to determine did user scrolled to the area where you placed apple, and If he did, you can add class to element to display it. When you add class to the element, animation will automatically start.

Comment: Sounds clear to me, but how can I determine if the user scrolled to the area?

Comment: You can use getBoundingClientRect() function to determine did user scrolled to the specific part of element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this: https://codepen.io/tateishi-e/pen/xaEJxw

```
function Utils() {}
        Utils.prototype = {
            constructor: Utils,
            isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
                var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
                var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
                var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

                if (fullyInView === true) {
                    return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
                } else {
                    return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
                }
            }
        };

        var Utils = new Utils();
        $(window).on('load', addFadeIn());
        
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            addFadeIn(true);
        });

function addFadeIn(repeat) {
            var classToFadeIn = ".will-fadeIn";
            
            $(classToFadeIn).each(function( index ) {
                var isElementInView = Utils.isElementInView($(this), false);
                if (isElementInView) {
                    if(!($(this).hasClass('fadeInRight')) && !($(this).hasClass('fadeInLeft'))) {
                        if(index % 2 == 0) $(this).addClass('fadeInRight');
                        else $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
                    }
                } else if(repeat) {
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeInRight');
                    $(this).removeClass('fadeInLeft');
                }
            });
        }
```

You can use his function to check if the element is visible to the viewport.